# How to print specific array entries from a .txt file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

First, I'm very new to coding in C++.
So, I have a .txt file, with names and numbers--here's an example.

chris 5

tara 7

Sam 13

Joey 15

I would like to use this code to retrieve the names and numbers, but how does one print specific array entries instead of just the variables name and number (I want it to show the name and the number on the screen)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string name;
int number;
struct sEntry
{
    std::string name;
    int number;
};
sEntry entries[256];
std::ifstream fin("input.txt"); // opens the text file
int nb_entries; // Keeps track of the number of entries read.

for (nb_entries = 0; fin.good() && nb_entries < 256;  nb_entries++) // Keep going until we hit the end of the file:
{
    fin >> entries[nb_entries].name;
    fin >> entries[nb_entries].number;
    cout << "Here, "<< name <<" is name.\n";
    cout << "Here, "<< number <<" is number.\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm? Oh, are you just trying to say that you don't think I've researched it enough?

Comment: This already prints all the entries.  What, specifically, is it you want to print?

Comment: When I compile & execute this program, it prints them incorrectly, leaving 'name' as a blank and 'number' as 2686760 (which it obviously isn't in the text file).  So now I'm stumped as to how to make it print "Here, chris is name." as well as "Here, 5 is number."

Comment: You never read anything into name and number variables, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing out `name` and `number`, but those aren't the variables you've read. You've read array entries.

Getting it working as simply as possible just comes down to changing your `cout` lines to be:

```
cout << "Here, " << entries[nb_entries].name << " is name.\n";
cout << "Here, " << entries[nb_entries].number << " is number.\n";
```

No need for a std::vector, ther's nothing wrong with how you've done it.

Comment: Besides the number of entries is implicitely limited to 256!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a plain C array of sEntry you should use a C++ vector instead (which can change size dynamically). Then you create a new sEntry instance inside your loop (which can just use fin.eof() as termination condition then) and use the operator>>() to assign the values. Afterwards you use push_back() to add the sEntry instances to your vector.
You need to use the sEntry.name, sEntry.number fields for output on the screen, name and number as shown in your code won't ever receive values.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct sEntry
{
    std::string name;
    int number;
};

int main() {
    string name;
    int number;
    std::vector<sEntry> entries;
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt"); // opens the text file
    // int nb_entries; // Keeps track of the number of entries read. -> not necessary, use entries.size()

    while(!fin.eof()) // Keep going until we hit the end of the file:
    {
        sEntry entry;
        fin >> entry.name;
        fin >> entry.number;
        cout << "Here, "<< entry.name <<" is name.\n";
        cout << "Here, "<< entry.number <<" is number.\n";
        entries.push_back(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoosh.  Ha, that kinda went over my head.
It comes up with the error message:

`C:\Jake\CodeBlocks\Load\main.cpp|16|error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::sEntry'|`

Comment: Just move the definition of sEntry out of the main function, then it should work. I'll correct my sample ...